# Select class only in this row - Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am using dependent drop down selects which works fine,
but I want them to be in a table so that more rows can be added as needed.

The problem I am having is that I am using a class to select the dropdown so options are added to all dropdowns not just the current row.

`$(".quote_product").append(option);`

Is the main offender and I have been trying to use:

`$(this).closest('tr').find(".quote_product").append(option);`

but this results in blank output.

My other thought was to apply IDs using the table row example #quote_product_1 etc but when I tried I kept getting index (-1).

HTML as below:
`

```
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>
    <select class="form-control quote_category">
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select class="form-control quote_product">
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
  <input type="input" name="quote_width" class="form-control quote_width" id="" placeholder="0.00" disabled="" />
  </td>
  <td>
  <input type="input" name="quote_qty" class="form-control quote_qty" id="" placeholder="1.00" />
  </td>
</tr>


<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>
    <select class="form-control quote_category">
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select class="form-control quote_product">
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
  <input type="input" name="quote_width" class="form-control quote_width" id="" placeholder="0.00" disabled="" />
  </td>
  <td>
  <input type="input" name="quote_qty" class="form-control quote_qty" id="" placeholder="1.00" />
  </td>
</tr>


<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>
    <select class="form-control quote_category">
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select class="form-control quote_product">
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
  <input type="input" name="quote_width" class="form-control quote_width" id="" placeholder="0.00" disabled="" />
  </td>
  <td>
  <input type="input" name="quote_qty" class="form-control quote_qty" id="" placeholder="1.00" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It is not clear how you appending options... On click, change, or (what is event, or you want to do it on page load)? Could you post complete code?

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you must use intersection selection if you are trying to target a specific dropdown list.
For example:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.form-control.quote_product').append(option);
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided or told us about the mechanism that's going to trigger adding the new option, so a full answer is not possible.

But it looks like it's going to be in the same tr as the select you want to add it to?  If so, your `$(this).closest('tr').find(".quote_product").append(` will work just fine.

Here's a demo that adds an option to the current row when you click in any of the right-most text boxes.  You'll just need to rewire the event to the button or whatever you put in that row.

```
$(".quote_qty").on("click", function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').find(".quote_product").append('<option value="3">added option</option>');
});
```